# Botones independientes con un mismo evento click

Tags: angular, ionic

soy nuevo en esto de la programación y tengo una duda con algo que creo que es simple pero no he dado con la solución, espero pueda ayudarme alguien.
Estoy haciendo una app en Ionic y tengo una sección generada con ngFor que tiene un numero con un botón + y otro - los cuales incrementan el numero o lo reducen si hago click respectivamente. Pero el problema está en que si tengo varios items, al presionar un botón se incrementan todos los números.
Este es mi método para incrementar

```
public click(){
  this.cantidad++;
  const mostrar: number = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('precio'))
  this.total = this.cantidad * mostrar;
  }
```

Y este es el HTML en la parte de los items

```
<div *ngFor="let item of comidas">
    <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
    <p>{{ item.price }}</p>

  <ion-row class="button-group">
    <ion-item class="item">
      <div>
        <ion-button (click)=clickMenos() color="white" class="boton">-</ion-button>
      </div>
    {{ cantidad }}
      <div>
        <ion-button (click)=click() color="white" class="boton">+</ion-button>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-row>
</div>
```

Así se ve, cada que presiono +, el numero aumenta en ambos items.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr lo que quieres debes modificar tu item para que incluya la `cantidad` y pasar por parametro tu `item` de esta manera:

```
public click(item){
  item.cantidad++;
  const mostrar: number = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('precio'))
  this.total = item.cantidad * mostrar;
  }
```

Y tu `html` quedaria asi:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of comidas">
    <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
    <p>{{ item.price }}</p>

  <ion-row class="button-group">
    <ion-item class="item">
      <div>
        <ion-button (click)=clickMenos(item) color="white" class="boton">-</ion-button>
      </div>
    {{ item.cantidad }}
      <div>
        <ion-button (click)=click(item) color="white" class="boton">+</ion-button>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-row>
</div>
```

Alternativamente puedes usar un objeto para relacionar estos datos si no posible modifcar el modelo de `item`.

> Debes adaptar la lógica que no expusiste aquí para que todo funcione correctamente.